# css not displaying when files are moved

Tags: css, vb.net, web

I'm sure there is something ridiculously simple here that I am missing but I just cant see it.  I have a number of template pages which are currently in the root folder of my project, as are 2 of my CSS sheets.  I have more contained in a "CSS" folder.  I want to take the the template pages (call them home.aspx and dashboard.aspx) and put them in a folder called "Template_Design_Pages".  I am happy to keep the CSS pages in the root directory, or move them.  When I move my template pages to the folder the CSS is lost.  I have tried updating the href's on the pages I have moved to no effect.  Say the href is href="css/Reset.css"  - i have tried changing to:

```
href="/css/Reset.css"
href="~/css/Reset.css"
href="Orion_Admin/css/Reset.css"  NB Orion_Admin is root.
```

I have seen this mentioned 
    href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/css/reset.css.css") %>" 
but it does not work either and I am not sure what it does.  I'm pretty new to all this.  The project is ASP.VB btw.  The following is the code which seems to be causing the trouble, although none of my images are showing up either.  I presume that it is all tied into the one issue though:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/text.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav.css" media="screen" />
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN: load jquery -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.effects.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.effects.slide.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Your paths are most certainly still wrong. Make note of exactly how you moved everything and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Try `href="../css/Reset.css"`

Comment: I have only moved one file and the code snippet is shown above.  The file moved is "Home.aspx"  I moved it to a sub folder called "Template_Design_Pages".  The css pages "layout.css" and "nav.css" are still within the root folder and the pages "reset.css", "text.css" and "grid.css" are in the sub folder ../css/  so I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would use an absolute path instead of a relative one.

```
<link rel="..." type="..." href="http://www.your.site/whatever/folder/reset.css" media="..:">
```

Also, instead of ~, try using ../ when moving up a folder.

Comment: I won't actually be hosting this project so I wont have a web address.  The href's aren't to link to other pages as such, they are just to call up the CSS pages, js pages and images